# snakemake equivalent to Python's `glob.glob()`

Tags: snakemake

I am writing a snakemake and for the first rule I should be able to parse its input from a partial string match.

So for example I have a list of `samples`, initially I would like to get as input the file

1. starting with the wildcard `sample`
2. having `R1` after the wildcard `sample`
3. ending with `fastq.gz`

To exemplify, considering the directory structure below,:

```
├── out
├── Snakefile
├── Snakefile.py -> Snakefile
└── Unaligned
    └── None-EF3
        ├── None-EF3_S101_R1_001.fastq.gz
        └── None-EF3_S101_R2_001.fastq.gz
```

given a list of samples `samples = ['None-EF3']`, I would like to create a file named `out/None-EF3.txt` with `None-EF3_S101_R1_001.fastq.gz` appended into it.

I have tried so far using python's `glob.glob()`, which I find very handy, though it appears it does not work with snakemake:

```
import glob
prefix = 'None'
samples = ['EF3']
workdir: 'out'
fqDir = 'Unaligned'

rule all:
    input:
        expand([
            "{sample}.txt"
        ], sample = samples)


rule echo:
    input:
        R1 = glob.glob(f"{fqDir}/{prefix}-{{sample}}/{prefix}-{{sample}}*R1*.gz")[0] # this will throw list index out of range Error, and removing the index [0] does not solve the problem
    output:
        "{sample}.txt"
    shell:
        "echo {input.R1} >> {output}"
```

My `samples` wildcards are somewhat set manually, so one solution would be to set `samples = ['EF3_S101']`, then restrict the wildcards to get `\d+` (to match `S101`), as the last portion `_001.fastq.gz` is always constant, yet this creates another problem that in my real workflow I am parsing files from directories withouth the `S_101` suffix (see the three above).

So what is the closest Python's `glob.glob()` in Snakemake to parse input files based on partial match?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I can get a list of input files using list comprehension inside a function:

```
import glob
import pathlib
import os
unalignedDir = 'Unaligned'

samples = ['None-EF3']


fqDir = 'Unaligned'


def get_reads(wildcards):
    readNames =  [f"{fqDir}/{wildcards.sample}/{read}" for read in os.listdir(f'{fqDir}/{wildcards.sample}') if "_R" in read]
    return readNames
    

rule all:
    input:
        expand([
            "out/{sample}.txt"
        ], sample = samples)


rule echo:
    input:
        get_reads
    output:
        "out/{sample}.txt"
    shell:
        "echo {input} >> {output}"
```

Comment: Yes, this has to be a function provided to `input` because snakemake needs to evaluate the list of inputs at the time of rule execution, rather than at the time of workflow evaluation.